# #ERROR when parsing .setFormulaR1C1()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having a hard time figuring out why the formula below won't parse when passed to `sheet.getRange('B2:B').setFormulaR1C1()`. It works in the sheet when I replace the R1C1 notation with A1 notation and nothing else.

Formula: `IF(R[0]C[4]="", "", VLOOKUP(R[0]C[4], sheet2!A:B, 2, 0))`

This one works: `IF(F2="", "", VLOOKUP(F2, sheet2!A:B, 2, 0))`

The only difference being the replacement of the R1C1 notation.

Because the script is actually populating the column with the R1C1 notation still there (it should be replaced with the column referenced in A1 notation to my knowledge), I believe the problem lies with the `.setFormulaR1C1()` function itself.

I've got another (different) formula with the same syntax but using ranges working directly above it using the same function. Yet this one will not parse, and I have no idea why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you cannot mix A1 and R1C1 notation. The correct formula which evaluates properly:

`IF(R[0]C[4]="", "", VLOOKUP(R[0]C[4], sheet2!C[-1]:C[0], 2, 0))`

Note the R1C1 notation has replaced the A1 notation in the second sheet reference.